# Expansion of Overlay Specification Macro

Tags: beamer, overlays

To  provide overlay specifications via a macro I have to use `\expandafter\item\foo text`, where `\foo` is something like `<+->`. When I do this often the `\expandafter` becomes bothersome. Is there a way to get rid of the `\expandafter`?

What I guess would work is to renew the overlay specification commands and add an `\expandafter`? Will this break anything?

Is there an easier way to ensure correct handling of the overlay macro, e.g. a beamer parameter or something?

Edit1: It seems when I instead use `\item<\foo> text` and let `\foo` be something like `+-` things work. I will use this and see if that answers the question.

Edit2: Below I added a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\def\foo{<+>}
\def\bar{<+->}
\begin{itemize}
\expandafter\item\foo First
\expandafter\item\bar Second
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\def\xitem{\expandafter\item}`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do it, but here it is. I'd much prefer giving the overlay options to `\begin{itemize}`: how many cases do you have where you'd like to apply this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
% similar to \@ifnextchar, tests if the next token is a control sequence
\newcommand{\@ifnextcs}[2]{%
  \def\reserved@a{#1}\def\reserved@b{#2}%
  \futurelet\@let@token\@ifncs
}
\def\@ifncs{%
  \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
    \let\reserved@c\@xifncs
  \else
    \if\noexpand\@let@token\relax
      \let\reserved@c\reserved@a
    \else
      \let\reserved@c\reserved@b
    \fi
  \fi
  \reserved@c
}

\let\ody@item\item
\def\item{\@ifnextcs{\expandafter\ody@item}{\ody@item}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\def\foo{<+>}
\def\bar{<+->}
\begin{itemize}
\item\foo First
\item\bar Second
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A different solution would be, of course, using `\xitem` defined by

```
\newcommand{\xitem}{\expandafter\item}
```

Comment: I will try to give the use case later.